# tab-completion only works for table names (mysql 5.5 on ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, autocomplete, ubuntu-14.04

I'm used to having tab-completion for mysql keywords, database names etc in mysql, but in my freshly installed mysql (via 'apt-get install mysql-server') it only works for table names, not database names.

I am supplying the --auto-rehash option when starting the mysql command line client interface. I'm aware that I can set this as a default via my.cnf, but I want to get it working first.

The [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html) tell me that the auto-rehash feature "requires a MySQL client that is compiled with the readline library."

'aptitude show mysql-client' tells me that I have 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.

For debugging purposes, how can I know if my mysql-client has readline, and if not, how do I get one that does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I wasn't specifying a database name when invoking the mysql command line interface!

Auto-completion works as expected if I go in as:

> mysql -u root -p mysql # or
>   mysql -u root -p mydatabase

as opposed to:

> mysql -u root -p

(and --auto-rehash clearly is on by default as per the docs)